# A vue composition api emitted multiple times before the following promise is ended

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

The 'state' below is emitted twice even though Promise is not ended. Well, I am aware that the each param     (successData, loading, errored) is emtted very well respectively. But whenever I merge them errors come up.

```js
import { computed, reactive, toRefs, watch, ref } from '@vue/composition-api';
import { Data } from '@vue/composition-api/dist/component';

export default function usePromise(fn: any) {
  if (!fn) {
    throw new Error(`[usePromise]: 1st argument is required (must be a function)`);
  }

  if (typeof fn !== 'function') {
    throw new TypeError(`[usePromise]: argument has to be function, but received ${typeof fn}`);
  }
  const state: any = reactive({
    successData: {},
    loading: true,
    errored: false,
    errorMessage: '',
    errorCode: 0,
    end: false,
  });

  let lastPromise;
  const use = async (...args: any) => {
    state.loading = true;
    const promise = (lastPromise = fn(...args));
    try {
      const result = await promise;
      if (lastPromise === promise) {
        state.successData = result.data;
        state.errored = false;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (!error.response) {
        state.errorCode = 900;
        state.errorMessage = 'Network Error';
      }
      state.errorMessage = error.response.data.error;
      state.errorCode = error.response.status;

      state.errored = true;
    } finally {
      state.loading = false;
      state.end = true;
    }
  };

  const responsePayload = computed(() => {
      return state;
  });
  return {
    responsePayload,
    use,
  };
}
```

That I gave it another try caused errors.

```
  const responsePayload = computed(() => {
    if (state.end === true) {
      return state;
    }
  });
```

```
 Invalid watch source: undefined.
      A watch source can only be a getter/effect function, a ref, a reactive object, or an array of these type
```

Also this kind of thing is not allowed. I just want the responsePayload emitted once only when the promise is ended

```
  const state: any = reactive({
    responsePayload : {
      successData: {},
      loading: true,
      errored: false,
      errorMessage: '',
      errorCode: 0,
      end: false,
    }
  });
```

Methods like Object.assign.. do not work.
I have no choice but to refer to all the data respectively like this.

```
function useUpdateResetToken(axios) {
  const { successData, errored, errorMessage, errorCode, loading, use: create } = usePromiseFn((toAddress) =>
    axios.post('/api/v1/admin/users/updateResetToken', { toAddress }),
  );
  const updateResetToken = (toAddress) => {
    return create(toAddress);
  };
  return { updateResetToken, successData, errored, errorMessage, errorCode, loading };
}
```

[Update]
This works but emits undefined.

```
import { computed, reactive, toRefs, watch, ref } from '@vue/composition-api';
import { Data } from '@vue/composition-api/dist/component';

interface PromiseFields {
  successData: any;
  loading: boolean;
  errored: boolean;
  errorMessage: string;
  errorCode: number;
}

export default function usePromise(fn: any) {
  if (!fn) {
    throw new Error(`[usePromise]: 1st argument is required (must be a function)`);
  }

  if (typeof fn !== 'function') {
    throw new TypeError(`[usePromise]: argument has to be function, but received ${typeof fn}`);
  }

  const _loading = ref(false);
  const state: any = reactive({
    successData: {},
    loading: computed(() => _loading.value),
    errored: false,
    errorMessage: '',
    errorCode: 0,
  });

  let lastPromise;
  const use = async (...args: any) => {
    _loading.value = true;
    const promise = (lastPromise = fn(...args));
    try {
      const result = await promise;
      if (lastPromise === promise) {
        state.successData = result.data;
        state.errored = false;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (!error.response) {
        state.errorCode = 900;
        state.errorMessage = 'Network Error';
      }
      state.errorMessage = error.response.data.error;
      state.errorCode = error.response.status;

      state.errored = true;
    } finally {
      _loading.value = false;
    }
  };

  const responsePayload = computed(() => {
    if (_loading.value === false) {
      return state;
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
  });
  return {
    responsePayload,
    use,
  };
}
```